# Display title if there are results

Tags: angularjs

I have some records, in each, there is an optionnal field `infoAdditionnelle` which is optionnal.

What i'am doing is a loop on my records, and display, for each record, the `title` and the `infoAdditionnelle` if the value of `infoAdditionnelle` exists.

In some cases, all the value of `infoAdditionnelle`  is empty in all the records, and in this case, i don't want the title of the section to be shown

See code : http://plnkr.co/edit/JdTeBcjnvvWgXqI0xn8q?p=preview

In this code, all the `infoAdditionnelle` are empty, so in this is case, i want to hide "my title", is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using angular filter, If all the `infoAdditionnelle` valuess are empty then title will not shown.

**Markup**

```
<p ng-if="(records|filter: {infoAdditionnelle: ""}: true).length == records.length">
My title</p>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgbgTeMueidpw1Gwf4Im?p=preview) here

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, but i want the title to be hidden if all `infoAdditionnelle` are empty

Comment: Doesn't work for me, when i have a not empty `infoAdditionnelle`, the title is never shown

Comment: Plus, you can't put "" inside other ""

Comment: @user Thats my bad, now you can take look at it, its final working, let me know if anything else is required

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-show="info"` to the element where your title appears, then do a simple `for` loop on your `records` within the controller to set `info` to `true` if `infoAdditionnelle.length` is greater than zero for any record. Otherwise `info` will remain false and your title will not be shown.

Note: `ng-if` would also work in place of `ng-show`. Whereas `ng-show` will set your title's element to `display: none`, `ng-if` will completely remove it from the DOM. Shouldn't make too much of a difference either way in this example, but just some good additional info to further your understanding.

html:

```
<p class="formtitle" ng-show="info">My title</p>
```

controller:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.records.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.records[i].infoAdditionnelle.length > 0) {
    $scope.info = true;
  }
}
```

See my plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4GKBjbc2DI7bcrJwDgo?p=preview).